# link-to route with an optional dynamic segment is undefined

Tags: ember.js

I have an "optional" dynamic segment on the index route.

Navigating to the index (http://foo.com) loads the default template, index.hbs.

Navigating to a dynamic segment on the index (http://foo.com/123) loads another template, chat.hbs.

**router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' });
  this.route('index', { path: '/:room_id' });
  ...
}
```

**routes/index.js**

```
model(params) {
  if (params.room_id) {
    this.set('templateName', 'chat');
    ...
  }
}
```

All is ok until using the link-to helper.
`{{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}`

This generates a link to `http://foo.com/undefined` instead of just `http://foo.com`

I have tried passing in a model to the link-to helper, but have not found a way to make it work.

Comment: Since you load a different template why not have a different route for it?

Answer (score 2):

Kitler answered my question in comments.

The solution is to create a new route for the dynamic segment.

**router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' });
  this.route('chat', { path: '/:room_id' });
  ...
}
```

**routes/chat.js**

```
model(params) {
    if (params.room_id) {
        return params.room_id;
    }
}
```